# Asp and javascript error : Message: Expected ')'

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I know this has been asked before and I've tried to use those solutions against my error, but I cannot get it to work using the solutions to past similar questions. The error message is that it expects a ')' . I've tried adding and removing parenthesis as well as removing single and double quotes but it still errors out each time?

```
protected void btnTestCS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

string result1 = "Failed: The samAccountName IdentityType must be in the form \"domainname\\userName\", \"machinename\\userName\", or \"userName\". | NN-NN-NN-01.NN.NN.NNNNN.NNN | CN=^sharing,OU=xxx_xxxxxx,OU=xxxxx,OU=xxxx,OU=xxx,OU=xxxxx,DC=xx,DC=xx,DC=xxx,DC=xxxxx)";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "errorRunExchangeShellMultiCommandsss", "javascript:showDialogError(" + result1 + ")" , true);

}

    function showDialogError(results) {
        results = results.replace("'", "\\'");
        results = results.replace("\"", "");
        $("#dialogFailureText").text(results);
        $("#dialogFailure").dialog({
            modal: true,
            title: 'Something went wrong',
            text: results,
            buttons: {
                OK: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }


        });
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing an opening '(' in your result1 string, but have ')' at the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Your actual JS code is fine, the code you are injecting is missing a closing bracket though

```
"...showDialogError(" + result1 + ")", true)
```

Comment: Believe it or not it still fails when I have that parenthesis as in your example. The debugger fails at this line. 

    javascript:showDialogError(Failed: The samAccountName IdentityType must be in the form "domainname\userName", "machinename\userName", or "userName". | xx-xx-xx-xx.xx.xx.xxxxx.xxx | CN=^xxx5,OU=xxxx_xxxx,OU=xxx,OU=xxx,OU=xxx,OU=xxx xxxx,DC=xx,DC=xxx,DC=xxxxx,DC=xxx)//]]>

The actual error text is: (next post)

Comment: Failed: The samAccountName IdentityType must be in the form "domainname\userName", "machinename\userName", or "userName". | xx-xx-xx-xx.xx.xx.xxxxx.xxx | CN=^xxx5,OU=xxxx_xxxx,OU=xxx,OU=xxx,OU=xxx,OU=xxx xxxx,DC=xx,DC=xxx,DC=xxxxx,DC=xxx

Comment: @Jay based on the code looks like you need to enclose the message in quotes i.e. `"...showDialogError(\"" + result1 + "\")", true)`

Answer (score 1):

There is an opening bracket here with no closing?

```
"javascript:showDialogError("
```

Answer (score 0):

I had multiple issues with my code, I had to add beginning and ending quotes in this part of the code `(\"" + returnValue + "\")"` . Then I had to replace any other double quotes inside of the error message string with single quotes as seen below and replace the single slash (which javascript read as a \u) with double slashes because Javascript was giving me a hexadecimal failure error because of the \u which is now \u.

All of this straightened out allows the asp code to pass an error message to a pretty Javascript box. Hopefully this helps someone else out.

```
returnValue = returnValue.Replace("\"", "'");
returnValue = returnValue.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "errorRunExchangeShellMultiCommands", "javascript:showDialogError(\"" + returnValue + "\")", true);
```